# Submitting HTML Form to Struts 2 Action class

Tags: html, forms, jsp, struts2

I am trying to submit HTML form to Struts 2 Action class, but after submitting the form, `Action` class is not getting triggered.

**JSP Page:**

**`Timesheet.jsp`**:

```jsp
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Team Activity Log</title>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableid)
{
 var table = document.getElementById(tableid);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
   
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("select");
    element1=document.getElementById("sele").cloneNode(true);
    element1.type="select";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);
    
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type="text";
    element2.setAttribute("placeholder","E.g:1234");
    cell2.appendChild(element2);
    
    var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type="text";
    element3.setAttribute("placeholder","Brief your work");
    cell3.appendChild(element3);
    
    var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type="text";
        element4.setAttribute("placeholder","MM min");
    cell4.appendChild(element4);
    
    
    var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
    var element5 = document.createElement("img");
    element5.src="close.png";
        element5.setAttribute("id","delete");
        element5.setAttribute("onclick","changeImage(this)");
    cell5.appendChild(element5);
    
    
    
    }
function changeImage(temp)
{
(temp.parentElement).parentElement.remove();
}
function convert(tableid,temp2)
{
var table=document.getElementById(tableid);
console.log(table.rows.length);
var hidelement=document.getElementById(temp2);
hidelement.setAttribute("value",table.rows.length-1);
for(var i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++)
{
var tt="tt"+i;
var rf="rf"+i;
var des="des"+i;
var eff="eff"+i;
console.log("executing function");
var elemen=table.rows[i].cells[0].querySelector("*");
elemen.setAttribute("name",tt);
elemen=table.rows[i].cells[1].querySelector("*");
elemen.setAttribute("name",rf);
elemen=table.rows[i].cells[2].querySelector("*");
elemen.setAttribute("name",des);
elemen=table.rows[i].cells[3].querySelector("*");
elemen.setAttribute("name",eff);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('matrix')" />
    <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
    <s:url id="myActionUrl" action="timesheetprocess" />
    <form action=<s:property value="%{myActionUrl}" />> 
    <input type="hidden" id="taskcount" value="5">
<table id="matrix">
<tr>
    <th>Task Type</th>
    <th>Reference ID</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Efforts</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <select id="sele">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
           <option value="SR">SR</option>
           <option value="CR">CR</option>
           <option value="ALM">ALM</option>
           <option value="INCIDENT">INCIDENT</option> 
           <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
   </select></TD>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="E.g:1234"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="Brief your work"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="MM min" />
   </td>
   <td>
   <img id="delete" src="close.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
   </td>
   </tr><tr>
  <td>
  <select id="sele">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
           <option value="SR">SR</option>
           <option value="CR">CR</option>
           <option value="ALM">ALM</option>
           <option value="INCIDENT">INCIDENT</option> 
           <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
   </select></TD>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="E.g:1234"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="Brief your work"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="MM min" />
   </td>
   <td>
   <img id="delete" src="close.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>
  <select id="sele">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
           <option value="SR">SR</option>
           <option value="CR">CR</option>
           <option value="ALM">ALM</option>
           <option value="INCIDENT">INCIDENT</option> 
           <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
   </select></TD>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="E.g:1234"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="Brief your work"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="MM min" />
   </td>
   <td>
   <img id="delete" src="close.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>
  <select id="sele">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
           <option value="SR">SR</option>
           <option value="CR">CR</option>
           <option value="ALM">ALM</option>
           <option value="INCIDENT">INCIDENT</option> 
           <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
   </select></TD>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="E.g:1234"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="Brief your work"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="MM min" />
   </td>
   <td>
   <img id="delete" src="close.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>
  <select id="sele">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
           <option value="SR">SR</option>
           <option value="CR">CR</option>
           <option value="ALM">ALM</option>
           <option value="INCIDENT">INCIDENT</option> 
           <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
   </select></TD>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="E.g:1234"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="Brief your work"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="MM min" />
   </td>
   <td>
   <img id="delete" src="close.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
   </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Submit" onclick="convert('matrix','taskcount')" />
 </form> 
   </body>
   </html>
```

Corresponding action tag in `Struts.xml` :

```
<action name="timesheetprocess" class="com.App.Controller.Timesheet.Timeprocess"
            method="execute">
    <result name="success">Time.jsp</result>
</action>
```

How to submit HTML form to Struts 2 action class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To submit a form you can use input element of type `submit`

```
<INPUT type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="convert('matrix','taskcount')" />
```

or as of you already using Struts tags

```
<s:submit value="Submit" onClick="convert('matrix','taskcount')" />
```